# How to insert a Calendar in java wicket

Tags: java, wicket-6

i want to insert a calendar in java wicket 6.19.I should be able to add events on specified dates.Is this possible?

Comment: http://www.7thweb.net/wicket-jquery-ui/calendar/ExtendedCalendarPage;jsessionid=028D74E400AAE2E5EDE827F1952B0BE5?0 .i tried using this but somehow i am not able to import import com.googlecode.wicket.jquery.ui.samples

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add or wrap *org.apache.wicket.extensions.markup.html.form.DateTextField* to choose some date but of course you have to handle it yourself.

Nice way can be get some nice jquery calendar component and wrap it in your custom wicket component.